# How to get post data from flask

Tags: python, flask

I cant figure out how to get post data from flask.

Below is my content-type

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Here is what I see from flask so I know the data is there.  I just cant access it.

```
request.values -> CombinedMultiDict([ImmutableMultiDict([]), ImmutableMultiDict([('{"email":"david","password":"FU"}', u'')])])
```

So...how do I get email and password?

```
email = request.?????
```

Answer (score 2):

Final solution that worked:

```
data = request.values.to_dict().keys()[0]
data = json.loads(data)
```

<sup>[source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33874787/3)</sup>

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Thank you this work for me. The above solution is perfect if you integrate a third party API and you can't modified. In my case I had to consume a POST request with json format on body with headers = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

Comment: can this be used for data stream?

Answer (score 1):

You can force Flask to treat the data as JSON using [request.get_json()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.get_json) setting the force argument to True

```
data = request.get_json(force=True)
```